# How to set up 3 categories for date format Oct-2023 across 2 years

Tags: formula, powerquery

I have one column with each cell contains text such as : Early Term; Transition, Unknown and different month and year in format MMM-YYYY such as: Jan-2024;Jun-2023;Jun-2024 etc. But i cannot sep up all those text and months into 3 categories in another column:
1.Previous months: if month before current month such Sep-2023,Jun-2023
2. Current and next 2 months: if month is current and next 2 months such as Nov-2023;Dec-2023 and if contains "Early  Term";"Transition"
3. Future months(excluding next 2 months) such as Jan-2024; "Unknown"

I tried in power query to setup conditional column but there is no comparison option as it is not Number date type. I tried to chang to data type :date or number, then there is error for cell with text.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide an example of your data (as **text** which can be copy/pasted) and also the expected results from that data. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you @Sam, I was calculateing the days difference . Your way of month difference will be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to create a few additional columns to get you there - then at the end once you have what you need, your can drop the additional columns.

1. Extract date part - select your column then go to `Add Column` in the ribbon and select `Extract` > `Last Characters` and enter count 9. In the formula bar, rename this new column from "Last Characters" to "MonthYear".
2. Select MonthYear column and change data type to Date.
3. Add a Custom Column with this formula: `(Date.Year([MonthYear]) * 12 + Date.Month([MonthYear])) - (Date.Year(DateTimeZone.FixedUtcNow())*12+Date.Month(DateTimeZone.FixedUtcNow()))`

This new column gives you the month difference from today. 0 = same month, -2 = two months ago, 3 = three months away etc... Now you have what you need to create your final column (Conditional Column) based on your needed logic.

Comment: Upvote for even understanding the question